# How to integrate nuxeo polymer 3 elements in angular app?

Tags: angular, polymer-3.x, nuxeo

I've built an Angular 6 app, and I need to include my Nuxeo Polymer 3 Elements (like this one https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-elements/blob/master/core/nuxeo-search.js).

How could I have something like:

```html
<app>
   <dom-bind>
      <template>
        <nuxeo-connection
          id="nx"
          url="http://localhost:8080/nuxeo"
          username="Administrator"
          password="Administrator"
        ></nuxeo-connection>
        <nuxeo-search auto searches="{{searches}}"></nuxeo-search>
        <div class="container" class="layout vertical center">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{searches}}">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="prop">
                <label class="propName">id:</label>
                <label class="propValue">[[item.id]]</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </template>
    </dom-bind>
</app>
```

Comment: I've created a sample repo for hosting polymer-3 components in a custom setup here: https://github.com/robertfoobar/polymer-3-web-component-sample This should also work for Angular 6

Comment: sorry, but not answering my question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some times, I can answer my question like explained [here](http://blog.mlefree.com/2019/05/how-i-integrated-nuxeo-web-components.html). In brief:

1. Enabling JS in angular in tsconfig.json :

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

2. Enabling custom elements schema in your app module:

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
...
@NgModule({   
...
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],   
...
})
```

3. `npm install` your components
4. Use a `<nuxeo-connection>` in the index.html file before any angular digest
5. Finally - in you app.component.html use your web components

```html
<nuxeo-document-suggestion
        [router]="router"
        (selected-item-changed)="select($event.detail.value)"
        placeholder="Select a document">
</nuxeo-document-suggestion>

<div *ngIf="doc">
  <nuxeo-page-provider #pp
                     auto
                     provider="advanced_document_content"
                     enrichers="thumbnail"
                     page-size="5"
                     [params]="params"
                     (current-page-changed)="onResults($event.detail.value)">
  </nuxeo-page-provider>
</div>
```

Cherry on the cake, Nuxeo web components are available for angular but also React and Vue.js.

Comment: npm install @nuxeo/nuxeo-elements @nuxeo/nuxeo-ui-elements -->throws 404 Not Found.How did you installed them?